# Working with list in Java

Tags: java, array

This code has a method that I call for in `main`.

I am given a list with temperatures.  What I need to do is to write out the biggest absolute difference of 2 neighbour numbers.  For example, if I have {1, 3, 4, 10, 7, 4}, the result is 6 (between 4 and 10) and also all other pairs that have the same difference.

I have this code written down but I feel it looks kind of clumsy. I'd be very grateful for any suggestions and improvements.

```
public class DN4 {
    static void najvecjaZaporednaRazlika(double stevila[]){
        double maxRaz = 0;
        double[] tStevil = new double[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < stevila.length - 1; i++){
            double a = stevila[i];
            double b = stevila[i+1];
            double absRaz = a - b;
            if (absRaz < 0){
                absRaz = -1 * absRaz;
            }
            if (absRaz == maxRaz){
                double tStevilStara[] = tStevil;
                tStevil = new double[tStevilStara.length+2];
                tStevil[tStevil.length - 2] = a;
                tStevil[tStevil.length - 1] = b;
                for (int t = 0; t < tStevilStara.length; t++){
                    tStevil[t] = tStevilStara[t];
                }
            }
            else if (absRaz > maxRaz){
                maxRaz = absRaz;
                tStevil = new double[2];
                tStevil[0] = a;
                tStevil[1] = b;
            }
        }
        System.out.printf("Najvecja razlika: %.2f\n",maxRaz);
        System.out.printf("Pari,ki dosezejo maksimalno razliko: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < tStevil.length - 1; i = i+2){
            if (i == 0){
                System.out.printf("(%.2f, %.2f)",tStevil[i],tStevil[i+1]);
            }
            else{
                System.out.printf(", (%.2f, %.2f)",tStevil[i],tStevil[i+1]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    } 

    public static void main (String args[]){
        double kredarica2011[] = {-7.8, -6.5, -5.7, -1.3, 1.7,  5,
                               5.6,  9.2,  7.1,  0.5, 0.3, -6.3};
        najvecjaZaporednaRazlika(kredarica2011);
    }  
}
```

Comment: @Vogel612: I got it now.  It just needed CTRL+K.

Comment: @Jamal I hate to put such stuff throught edit-queue and not even notify OP about it... It feels so intrusive..

Comment: @Vogel612: That's just the nature of it.  In most cases, others will review the edits.

Comment: @user2956514 The most obvious advice would be just use an `ArrayList` save yourself a lot of trouble, but I'm guessing this is a homework and you are supposed to use arrays. Your naming is probably bad but you can't get them reviewed because you didn't care to translate them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### General

- Your code style is neat. I like that you are using `System.out.printf` instead of concatenating strings. You should consider using `%n` instead of `\n`in the format because it is platform independent.
- Math.abs() - `Math.abs()` is a core function that you should use instead of doing it yourself.
- Growing the tStevil array - you do this manually, and you increase and decrease the size often. This can be inefficient. It may be better to keep a big-enough version, and have a separate `int tStevillength` variable to keep track of how much is actually populated.
- This code here:

  > ```
  >     for (int i = 0; i < tStevil.length - 1; i = i+2){
  >         if (i == 0){
  >             System.out.printf("(%.2f, %.2f)",tStevil[i],tStevil[i+1]);
  >         }
  >         else{
  >             System.out.printf(", (%.2f, %.2f)",tStevil[i],tStevil[i+1]);
  >         }
  >     }
  > ```

  would be better done with less code repeated:

  ```
  for (int i = 0; i < tStevil.length - 1; i = i+2){
      if (i > 0){
          System.out.print(", ");
      }
      System.out.printf("(%.2f, %.2f)",tStevil[i],tStevil[i+1]);
  }
  ```

### Algorithm.

Your algorithm is close to what I would have done. The only difference is that I would keep an array of indexes of the first member of a temperature pair....

Also, sometimes it is easier to loop from `i = 1`, instead of looping to `i < length - 1`

My code would look something like:

```
int pairlen = 0;
int[] pairs = new int[stevila.length];
double maxdiff = Double.MIN_VALUE;
for (int i = 1; i < stevila.length; i++) {
    double diff = Math.abs(stevila[i] - stevila[i - 1]);
    if (diff > maxdiff) {
        maxdiff = diff;
        pairlen = 0;
    }
    if (diff == maxdiff) {
        pairs[pairlen++] = [i - 1];
    }
}
```

This way, at the end of the loop, you have the index to the first pair of `pairlen` indexes for values with the largest diff.

You can then loop through that list using `for (i = 0; i < pairlen; i++) { .... }` and pull the actual values back from the `stevila` array.

This is not actually very different fdrom the way you have done it, but it is a bit neater.

Nice job.

Comment: I really appreciate you taking time and for giving me a great answer :)